# How to disable chunking in .NET 6 ASP CORE API Controller response?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

To properly return an API response I currently have this funky code:

```
 DoughnutChart dc = new DoughnutChart();


 var js = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dc);    

 Response.Headers.Add("Content-Length", new Microsoft.Extensions.Primitives.StringValues(js.Length.ToString()));

 return new OkObjectResult(dc);
```

What do I need to do so that the response is not chunked and I can have my code like this?

```
  DoughnutChart dc = new DoughnutChart();

  return new OkObjectResult(dc);
```

Comment: What is `DoughnutChart`?Can you share about it?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out that this is the default behavior: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/25448